# Java processes remain alive after CRON

Tags: java, cron

I created a jar that grabs an image from a URL (webcam of my favorite beach) and saves it to a file using the timestamp as a name. Yes, I know there are programs to do this - I'm a propellerhead and I wanted to do it myself. It works like a champ.

Then I scheduled it to run every minute with CRON. Again, worked like a champ.

```
* * * * * java -jar /apps/clearcapture.jar
```

After running for several hours (Mac OS 10.9) I found the machine running at a crawl. Activity Monitor revealed MANY java processes. Without counting them, I would guess that there was one instance for every time the image was captured.

So, what's going on here? I expect that when the jar is done, its parent Java instance would go away.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Might be a dumb question but when you run your java program from the command line do you see it appear on your process list only to drop off quickly once it finishes?

Comment: Yes it should go away but it could be lingering because of unclosed resources. Make sure you have all threads terminated and all input/output streams closed. Also do as @JasonSperske says and try it once and make sure the process ends. There is a program that is extremely usefull called visualvm that comes with your JDK found at jdk1.7.0\bin\jvisualvm.exe. I would recommend it for this situation

Comment: Jason set me in the right direction. I ran it from the command line and after it did its thing, it failed to return to the command prompt, indicating that "something" was still going on. I resolved it by explicitly closing the HTTPUrlConnection at the conclusion of the download.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of main method of the main class, you should call **System.exit** to explicitly exit the program. For better exception handling, you should capture all exceptions, log them into a proper log and call System.exit with system error output.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by explicitly closing the HTTPUrlConnection at the conclusion of the download.